# Java Jackson Deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I struggled a while trying to find way to deserialize this following structure into java object using fasterxml.jackson.

Obviously the "NewYork" and "Boston" are the keys, not an schema I must unmarshall into map

```
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString,
                    new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});
```

But the jsonMap return is LinkedHashMap, with key is "NewYork", value is another LinkedHashMap. In the second inner map, the key is "schedules", and value are list of LinkedHashMap.  The third inner map, the key, value are
"date": "2020-10-31",
"flightNo": "UA110",
"depart": "17:30PM"

What I want is java model like this

```
public class FlightInfo {

   Map<String, List<Schedule>> info;
}
```

I did some search, thinking about JsonNode, Json node must know the property name, in my case, NewYork and Boston are not determined.

I could not find way to do that.

```
{
  "NewYork": {
    "schedules": [
      {
        "date": "2020-10-31",
        "flightNo": "UA110",
        "depart": "17:30PM"
      },
       {
        "date": "2020-11-01",
        "flightNo": "UA230",
        "depart": "18:30PM"
      }
    ]
  },
 "Boston": {
    "schedules": [
      {
        "date": "2020-11-01",
        "flightNo": "AM110",
        "depart": "08:00AM"
      },
       {
        "date": "2020-11-01",
        "flightNo": "CA230",
        "depart": "10:30AM"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please edit the question and post the code you are trying and specific issues. thanks  have you looked here -http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html#read-object-from-json-string

Comment: Thanks @OldProgrammer, I did not find anything useful in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string is not adapt to your expected data model `Map<String,Object>` or `Map<String, List<Schedule>>`. Actually there are two level mappings, **NewYork -> schedules -> List Of Schedule**

So we should use the below TypeReference with two level Map to do deserialize

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, List<Schedule>>>>(){});
```

Certainly, if you persist to use one level mapping, you could modify the data, like the following. And thus we could use a simple version `TypeReference<Map<String, List<Schedule>>>`

```
{
  "NewYork": [
      {
        "date": "2020-10-31",
        "flightNo": "UA110",
        "depart": "17:30PM"
      },
       {
        "date": "2020-11-01",
        "flightNo": "UA230",
        "depart": "18:30PM"
      }
 ],
 "Boston": [
      {
        "date": "2020-11-01",
        "flightNo": "AM110",
        "depart": "08:00AM"
      },
       {
        "date": "2020-11-01",
        "flightNo": "CA230",
        "depart": "10:30AM"
      }
    ]
}
```